# Updating Django's JSONField

Tags: django, django-jsonfield

Let's say I have a model:

```py
class Foo(Model):
    bar = JSONField(...)
```

I can easily filter by the elements of `bar`. For example,

```py
Foo.objects.filter(bar__has_key="some_key").count()
```

will give me the number of `Foo` objects that have `"some_key"` as a key in their `bar` field.

My question is about updates. I tried:

```py
Foo.objects.exclude(bar__has_key="some_key").update(bar__some_key={"x": "y"})
```

to set the value to some default where it isn't set, but that gives me

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Foo has no field named 'bar__some_key'.
```

I can, of course, do

```py
objs = list(Foo.objects.exclude(bar__has_key="some_key"))
for obj in objs:
    obj.bar["some_key"] = {"x": "y"}
Foo.objects.bulk_update(objs, ["bar"])
```

but I'm interested if this can be done without looping (and generating potentially large `Foo` objects in memory), using only `QuerySet.update`.

Additionally, I'd be curious how to remove `"some_key"` from all objects that have it. So, this:

```py
objs = list(Foo.objects.filter(bar__has_key="some_key"))
for obj in objs:
    del obj.bar["some_key"]
Foo.objects.bulk_update(objs, ["bar"])
```

but again using only `QuerySet.update`.